# Is it possible to implement an inheritance like mechanism for React components in order to reduce nearly duplicate code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I find that I am having to reimplement a lot of the same functionality. For example, with the next 3 components I am implementing the same code for `style`, `className` and `id`. I know that I can have `{...props}` as the argument instead hear, and then pass `{...props}` to the container inside the return function, but I am not able to do this if I want these components to each have their own classNames and styles that are always assigned to each instance of these classes. I looked into [higher-order-components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) a bit, but couldn't wrap my head around how I would use them in this case

```
const styles = {
    container:{
        position: 'absolute'
    },
}

const Modal = ({className, style, id, hidden, children}) => {

    return (
        <div 
            className={`modal ${className}`}
            style={...{styles.container}, ...{style}}
            id={id}
        >
            {!hidden && <ExtraContent />}
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

```
const styles = {
    container:{
        margin: 10
    }
}

const VoteButton = ({className, style, id, pressed}) => {
    let img
    if (pressed){
        img = './img_pressed.jpg'
    }else{
        img = './img_not_pressed.jpg'
    }
    return (
        <div
            className={`voteButton ${className}`}
            style={...{styles.container}, ...{style}}
            id={id}
        >
            <img src={img}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

```
const styles = {
    container:{
        display: 'flex'
    }
}

const Navbar = ({className, style, id, links, children, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <nav 
            {...props}
            className={`navbar ${className}`}
            style={...{styles.container}, ...{style}}
            id={id}
        >
            {links.map(lk => <a href={lk.href}>{lk.text}</a>
            {children}
        </nav>
    )
}
```

---

To be clear, I am looking for a way to avoid having to define and modify `className`, `style` and `id` for each component. It would be good if I could do this once. I understand this might be especially hard for the third component considering it's a `nav` instead of a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to have a function that returns your component function:

```
function createComponentClass(Ele, name, styles, children) {
  return (props) => {
    const { className, style, id } = props;
    return (
      <Ele className={`${name} ${className}`} style={...{styles.container}, ...{style}} id={id}>
        {children(props)}
      </Ele>
    );
  };
}

const Modal = createComponentClass('div', 'modal', { container: { ... } }, (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {!props.hidden && <ExtraContent />}
      {props.children}
    </>
  );
});

const VoteButton = createComponentClass('div', 'voteButton', { container: { ... } }, (props) => {
  let img = pressed ? './img_pressed.jpg' : './img_not_pressed.jpg';
  return <img src={img} />;
});

const Navbar = createComponentClass('nav', 'navbar', { container: { ... } }, (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {links.map(lk => <a href={lk.href}>{lk.text}</a>
      {children}
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: Ok, I think this answer will work. One thing I'm still a bit confused about would be if `styles.container` is different for each component(I've updated my question). Would the answer just be to add another argument to `createComponentClass` so that it is something like `createComponentClass(Ele, name, defaultStyle){` create all three styles and pass them in to the function calls?

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Ok, and sorry, one more question. I updated my question to reflect cases where there are some props that are required by some components, but they are not required by the other components. As well the code within the outer container is different for each component. I feel like this is a more typical use case of what I'm looking for

Comment: What is the purpose of the `hidden` prop for `Modal`?

Comment: I just updated my question. It's a toy example though to show how each of these components has slightly different functionality

Comment: You can pass it a function that takes `props` and returns the JSX you want inside your component. I updated my answer to reflect this change.